# Attendance recording software

Tags: attendance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What systems are most effective for monitoring student attendance?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5170/what-systems-are-most-effective-for-monitoring-student-attendance)

I'm looking for a simple software package, or online service, whereby teachers can record any students that are late/absent for any of their classes throughout the day. I'm not after a daily attendance system, I need a system that can be easy and quick for teachers to log attendance of students to their classes. Is there any such thing? If not, what do you recommend? a wiki? or something else?