# How to keep track of attendance and student-submitted excuses for absences?

Tags: teaching, grades, attendance

I will be teaching an introductory class, in which attendance is important, with approximately 60 students in 3 sections.  I'd like to have a system that:

1. Enables me to quickly mark whether a student is present.
2. Allows students to see their own attendance record but not other students'.
3. Lets students provide information about their absences.

For small classes, students email me (or I email them) for information about absences, but it would be overwhelming with this many students.

A single Google spreadsheet would be great for data entry, and students could use comments to annotate their absences, but it wouldn't protect students' privacy.

Any suggestions (besides not tracking attendance)?  My school provides Google Apps and Blackboard, although I'm willing to use other solutions.

**UPDATE**: I know a hack that would work in Blackboard would be to create a fake assignment for each day (attending class) and enter attendance information (0 or 1) there.  This is not ideal because (1) entering data into Blackboard is slower than putting it into a spreadsheet, (2) it would bloat the grade listings seen by the students, and (3) I don't think students could add a comment to the "grade" (the excuse).

There is a [similar question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5170), but it does not address how to incorporate excuses/explanations, which, to me, is the tricky part.

Comment: "in which attendance is important" -- why? What do you or your students gain from enforcing that?

Comment: @Raphael It could be, for instance, that there are departmental/university wide policies on automatic failures due to absences.  There are very real reasons for attendance policies in classes like band/choir/theatre where if half the class skips out, the other half can't adequately have the expected class (trying properly doing a choir rehearsal with only a random third of the choir every day). If you have an attendance policy, but don't take roll... you're opening yourself up to students disputing any reduction you give them for non-attendance

Comment: @guifa My question was about enforcing attendance, not enforcing an attendance policy. Of course, if you have one you've got to implement it. I think you shouldn't have one, though.

Comment: @Raphael Your comment is off-topic.  This forum is not for unsolicited advice.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question differs from the ["duplicate"](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5170/what-systems-are-most-effective-for-monitoring-student-attendance) one due to the need to handle student excuses for being absent.

Comment: @MadJack Concur; I also see that this question aims to make the information available back to students, which is much more difficult than just tracking within a group of instructors.

Comment: @espertus I don't follow. It seems to me that the point of your question (and many others on this site) is getting (subjective or experience-driven) advice.

Comment: I don't think that attendance of the lectures is so important. It may vary for the students. When I was an undergraduate student, I have had top grades and even maximum without going to one of the lectures. I had considered that after studying at home for 3 hours I would be more advanced than after 3-4 courses. However, in some cases for some subjects, attendance is crucial.

Comment: @Raphael I'm sorry for not noticing your question until now. The reason that I objected to your comment was that I was soliciting opinions on technology on recording absences, not on whether I should be recording absences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a sort of a solution using Google Apps, but it's **ugly** and it's still very much imperfect (more on that at the bottom).

You could create a master spreadsheet (that for the sake of example has the internal ID of "masterSheet") that looks like this:

```
      A          B         C         D         E         F
1| Name       | 9/1 | 9/1 Comment | 9/2 | 9/2 Comment | etc.
2| Student A  |     |             |     |             |
3| Student B  |     |             |     |             |
4| Student C  |     |             |     |             |
```

Then you'll create another spreadsheet for Student A:

```
    A            B                                C
1| Date | Attendance Grade                 | Comment/Excuse
2| 9/1  | =IMPORTRANGE("masterSheet","B2") |
3| 9/2  | =IMPORTRANGE("masterSheet","D2") |
3| etc. | =IMPORTRANGE("masterSheet","X2") |
```

You'll then make columns A and B (as well as cell C1) uneditable except by you.  You don't necessarily need to type in the `IMPORTRANGE()` stuff manually, and you do it formulaicly much easier if you have both the master and student spreadsheets go in the same order (although it's possible either way).

Initially, the student will just see

```
    A            B                                C
1| Date | Attendance Grade                 | Comment/Excuse
2| 9/1  |                                  |
3| 9/2  |                                  |
3| etc. |                                  |
```

As you put in their attendance grades for each day, it will show up automatically in theirs, but they won't be able to edit it if you properly protect the range.  Now, for their comments.  You'll do the exact same thing, but in reverse, and you'll get:

```
      A          B         C                           D         E                           F
1| Name       | 9/1 | 9/1 Comment                   | 9/2 | 9/2 Comment                   | etc.
2| Student A  |     | =IMPORTRANGE("studentA","C2") |     | =IMPORTRANGE("studentA","C3") |
3| Student B  |     | =IMPORTRANGE("studentB","C2") |     | =IMPORTRANGE("studentB","C3") |
4| Student C  |     | =IMPORTRANGE("studentC","C2") |     | =IMPORTRANGE("studentC","C3") |
```

If a student enters in a comment in their spreadsheet, it will show up on yours.

Now, a few comments about this:

It's **ugly**.  It's awful.  But it basically does what you want.  But there's also a security consideration that will greatly reduce its efficacy to be effectively useless.  Besides the fact that a student could get access to your original spreadsheet by using `IMPORTRANGE()` on their comment field, Google Apps requires a user to have viewing or editing privileges to the document referenced by `IMPORTRANGE()`.  There are many ways ways to obfuscate, but it will only ever be obfuscation, and not real security.

### What you should do from my experience

Just use Blackboard.  It does NOT take that long to take roll with it.  It *is* a spreadsheet.  On day one of the semester, I take five minutes and create a column for each day of class, and then don't have to worry about it again (and if you're teaching the same classes, ideally they're on the same schedule and you can either merge the course or clone the course so you only do it once for all three).  Then each day I just hit in `5,enter,0,enter,5,enter,5,enter,5,enter,0,enter` (5 is fully present in my personal system, 0 is absent).

All the attendance columns get pushed to the bottom of the student's view (the right of the instructor's view) by using *Grade Center -> Manage -> Column Organization*.

For students to contact you, make it clear they must use a standard subject line that can be caught and filtered in your e-mail program into a specific e-mail excuse box.  If I accidentally marked them as absent and they weren't, or if they had an excuse, they are instructed to e-mail me using a subject line CC'd to themselves that begins "Attendance:" and that gets filtered into an attendance folder for that semester (you may want them to also add in a section, if you don't have merged courses) where I can then deal with it.  At the end of the semester, I have students verify that I properly tended to any necessary changes in attendance grades and then the one or two mistakes (if any) can be fixed then.

I regularly deal with 120 students a semester (4 sections x 30 students) and have had no problems with this set up.

Unless you have an attendance-specific module in Blackboard that provides the functionality you want, you are going to have problems finding anything that is FERPA-compliant or that is not going to be a giant PITA to use.

Comment: Thank you.  Out of curiosity, do they remember to use the special subject line?

Comment: @espertus For the most part, yeah.  I tell them anything that doesn't follow it is filtered automatically into the trash (maybe when I'm an older grouchier academic, I'll actually have it do that...).  If they don't and it flows into your normal mailbox, it's up to you whether you want to deal with it and manually move it to that mailbox since your syllabus would have told them otherwise or just trash it.

Comment: I think I'll also ask them to cc their TA, whose responsibility it will be to update the Blackboard record from Disappeared to Acknowledged.

Answer (score 3):

For a multi-section course with this many students, you really should make use of a Learning Management System (Blackboard in your case) for an online gradebook and attendance tracking system that allows students to see their grades and attendance records.  My experience is with Canvas and Moodle rather than Blackboard, so I won't attempt to answer this question in detail, but I'm sure that Blackboard should be able to do this.

At another level, you'll need to record who actually shows up each day.  You can enter the information by hand, or you might consider using an audience response system ("clicker") and have the students check themselves in.  For large lecture courses this works very well.

Comment: A possible downside to using clickers for attendance: if a student who intends on being absent gives their clicker to a friend in the class and the friend checks them in. I don't know how problematic this is in practice, though.

Comment: Thank you. We aren't using clickers, although we are using computers they have to sign in to, so I might be able to use those.  Blackboard does not provide the desired functionality.

Comment: @MadJack Some of my colleagues have caught students doing that.   That's cheating, and with a sufficiently robust punishment (e.g. the threat of an F in the course) it's easy enough to stop.  I've never had any problems with it in my classes.

Comment: @espertus you can simply make an assignment for each day "attend class" and then either award 0 points or 100 points depending on whether or not the student showed up that day.

Comment: I neglected to say that I don't consider entering data into Blackboard to a lightweight task.  It's also ugly to create a column in the grades for each day.

Answer (score -2):

Whether using clickers or a mere sign-in sheet, I typically give the class a few minutes (to allow for stragglers), and then at a convenient take-a-breath point, double-check the number of registered clickers/signatures against the number of heads actually present.  If they don't match we have A Very Serious Situation that I will bring class to a halt to address (since they do, indeed, invariably believe it's No Big Deal to sign in for others). 
If necessary, ask those with clickers to hold them above their heads as they answer a trivial question, to confirm that no one is holding up two or more, and then check the record later to see which in-class remote was not triggered for that question. That person is, as Richelieu would say, TOAST.

(Alas, this is obviously impractical for auditorium-sized sections, in which the issue usually needs to be addressed the most often.  In those, I augment the clickers with signature sheets every once in a while so that I can scan for identical handwriting on consecutive names. Not perfect, but a start.)

Comment: And what is stopping a cheater from showing his clicker with his right hand and holding the extra one on his left, under the table?

Comment: (For that matter. what prevents a cheater from implementing a clicker-spoofer app on their cell phone to simulate ten of their friends?)

Comment: @Davidmh, I would do this only for the smaller classrooms, where I've got clear line of sight (<20 feet) to all students.  In an auditorium, there would indeed be no point to trying it.  (I'd also be asking them to keep their other hand on the desk, just in case, since oh yes they do indeed love to keep an extra smartphone concealed in the lap.)

Comment: @JeffE, I am _highly interested_ in the spoofing apps you described; any names to look into?  To combat it, I would still rely on the head-count (again, why it'll never work in a large auditorium).  Should I get 30 responses in a room of 20, I would _immediately_ bring the class to a halt and pass around a roll sheet. Those not actually present have  been revealed to have used a friend to "sign the roll" for them, in a class in which participation is a (tiny) part of the grade. Thus, they have just falsified the academic record of the class in order to achieve a higher grade. ACADEMIC FRAUD.

Comment: In one auditorium course, I brought in a cheating case the roll sheets that showed that the "good" student whose tests bore evidence of copying (identical arithmetic mistakes only at the same 3 moments) by the "weak" students had been signing them in (her handwriting) for weeks. Very unlikely they had ever been present at all. Before the Academic Council, the effort to obscure their absence was viewed by the (otherwise skeptical) faculty as genuine evidence of intent on her part (not just that she was unwittingly spied upon), and all were given an F.

Comment: She later came to my office and tearfully admitted, "I think my friends took advantage of me."

Comment: If you have only 30 students, you really don't need clickers. If you have 400 (as I will next semester), then one student impersonating ten is undetectable noise. No, I don't know of any spoofing apps/devices, but I don't know of _any_ reason that a bright, motivated student couldn't build one, so I assume they must exist.

Comment: Aha. [Found one.](http://www.taylorkillian.com/2012/11/turning-point-clicker-emulation-with.html)

Comment: Ha...love the immediate re-response follow-up. Yeah, if we think a student has thought up some new method of chicanery, it _probably_ won't take us very long to find one. #Rule11 Oh, the effort they will go to just to avoid a 10am class. Thanks, @JeffE!

Comment: BTW, FWIW, my purpose in a smallish class using clickers is twofold: to keep them engaged more actively (after watching too many come to class and sleep to get around the school's attendance requirements), and because my own attendance-taking capabilities are often inhibited by my difficulty recognizing faces (even extended family members, at times). If you're _really_ active, I might remember, but it helps just to have a bit of a paper-trail backup.